# If no current is able to flow through a capacitor what will be the node voltage on the other end of the capacitor opposite the voltage source?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, voltage, capacitance, batteries

I'm working on a simple circuit problem including a capacitor and I am calculating the node voltage Va.
By using KVL, I find that Va is 5V. But how does the 5 volts appear on at Va if it is not connected to the voltage source? Since no current can flow through the capacitor, it is basically an open circuit, but whenever I do KVL, Va is always equal to 5V. Also, say if the voltage source increases from 0V to 5V, how does the node voltage at Va also increase from 0V to 5V? I don't understand how the voltage at Va is always equal to the voltage across the voltage source. Any help/explanation is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may start tracking the voltage from where is grounded, the point set 0 voltage. I copy your figure as follows, and marked some positions for explanation.

[image]

The point $A$ is grounded, i.e. $V_A = 0$, and there is no voltage difference between point $B$ and point $A$, therefore $V_B = 0$. The voltage will be increased by $5 V$ for point B and point C, across the voltage source.

Then, since there are no charges in the capacitor, the voltage drop across the capacitor is zero $V_c = \Delta Q / C = 0$. This renders point $D$ has the same voltage as point $C$, i.e. $V_D = V_C = 5 V$.

Comment: That makes sense, but what if the voltage source starts at 0V and increases to 5V, how does the voltage at point D also increase from 0V to 5V? Is there a way to explain it physically? Based on Vc = dQ/C,  I can see how this would increase point D's voltage from 0V to 5V as well, but how does the strip of wire where D is at suddenly gain potential? Say if the strip of wire at D is a foot away from C, doing KVL will still provide the same result, this seems really strange to me for some reason. Thanks

Comment: @JerryHsieh Ohhhh...It should be say that he voltage of point D is 5 Volt higher that the ground at point A.  Because there is no current in the lead, it gives no voltage drop, therefore point C and point D have a same voltage independent of the physical length.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: @JerryHsieh Welcome.